# Return Cookie along with Object from .NET Web API

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpcookie

I'm using .NET Web API and I wish to send the newly created cookie along with the string which was generated in the Web API.

The C# Code:

```
public Tuple<HttpResponseMessage, string> CookieMessage()
{
        string result = "Cookie Created Successfully !";

        CookieHeaderValue serverCookie = new CookieHeaderValue("", "");

        serverCookie = new CookieHeaderValue
                                ("IEM", "Success");
        serverCookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15);
        serverCookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
        serverCookie.Path = "/";


    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { serverCookie });

    return Tuple.Create(response, result);

}
```

How could I send the response `"Cookie Created Successfully !"` along with the Cookie **`serverCookie`**

Kindly assist me how to send these two in a single response to the client. I'm getting the **500 Internal Server Error**

I seen the following message in the Response

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize  the response body for
>   content type 'application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"
>   ,"StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error getting  value from
>   'SeparatorsArray' on
>   'System.Version'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"
>   ,"StackTrace":"   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)\r\n    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter
>   writer , Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract & memberContract, Object&
>   memberValue)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
>   .SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract
>   contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract 
>   collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
>   .SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract
>   valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract 
>   containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
>   .SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract
>   contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract 
>   collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
>   .SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract
>   valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract 
>   containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
>   .SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract
>   contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract 
>   collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
>   .SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract
>   valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract 
>   containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
>   .Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal (JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter ,
>   Object value)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClassd.
>
> > b__c()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action,
> >     CancellationToken  token)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has
> >     occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Common Language Runtime  detected an
> >     invalid
> >     program.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidProgramException","StackTrace":"
> >     at GetSeparatorsArray (Object )\r\n   at
> >     Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
> >     target)"}}}

Comment: Have you run it under a debugger to see what exception is thrown?

Comment: @fahadash In Web API, it returns without any exception. I pasted the response. Kindly check it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an unsupported type. I am sure that the framework will never be able to serialize `Tuple<HttpResponseMessage, string>`. If you want to modify the response headers you need to return just `HttpResponseMessage`.

This should work as you expect:

```
public HttpResponseMessage CookieMessage()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<string>(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        "Cookie Created Successfully !"
    );

    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("IEM", "Success");
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15);
    cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
    cookie.Path = "/";

    response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

    return response;
}
```